# SQL- Como puedo agrupar datos repetidos en una sola fila segun este codigo?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedure, reportviewer, aplicación-escritorio

```
(select t1.ACODIGO,t1.ADESCRI,t1.AUNIDAD,t1.Linea,t1.Linea2 from(
            SELECT  
              row_number() over (partition by decodigo,datepart(month,CAFECDOC) order by CAFECDOC desc, CATIPMOV desc ,CACODMOV desc,CAALMA desc,CATD desc,CANUMDOC desc,DEITEM desc)[Fila],
              DECODIGO as ACODIGO,DEDESCRI as ADESCRI,DEUNIDAD as AUNIDAD,
             (case when DATEPART(month, CAFECDOC)=MONTH(GETDATE()) -1  then cast(DEPRECIO as money)  else 0 end) Linea,
             (case when DATEPART(month, CAFECDOC)=MONTH(GETDATE()) then cast(DEPRECIO as money)  else 0 end) Linea2
             from
             [025BDCOMUN].DBO.MOVALMCAB AS B INNER JOIN (MOVALMDET AS A 
                     LEFT JOIN MAEART AS M ON A.DECODIGO = M.ACODIGO) ON B.CAALMA = A.DEALMA AND B.CATD = A.DETD AND B.CANUMDOC = A.DENUMDOC
                     WHERE  
         YEAR(CAFECDOC) = '2020' AND 
       CASITGUI <> 'A' AND 
       NOT (CATD = 'GS' AND CACODMOV = 'GF' AND CASITGUI = 'F') AND 
       NOT (M.AFSTOCK = 'N' AND M.AFSERIE = 'N' AND M.AFLOTE = 'N') 
      AND DECODIGO like '100%' 
      AND (DECODIGO <> 'TEXTO')
      AND M.AFAMILIA >= '001' AND M.AFAMILIA <= '027') t1
            where [Fila]=1 
            group by [Fila],t1.ACODIGO,t1.ADESCRI,t1.AUNIDAD,t1.Linea,t1.Linea2)
            order by ACODIGO
```

ME SALE ESTE RESULTADO

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PERO INTENTE DE MUCHAS FORMAS Y NO ME SALE DE ESTA MANERA

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

LA UNICA SOLUCION QUE ENCONTRE FUE AGRUPARLO EN REPORTVIEWER PERO QUISIERA QUE ME SALGA EN SQL PORFAS.

Comment: Los datos de ejemplo que muestras no parecen tener ninguna relación, o fallas en explicar ¿de dónde sale el `ACIDO (3.785 L.)` de los resultados que esperas, a partir de los datos del resultado que obtienes actualmente?

Comment: En otras palabras, ni viendo el código ni los datos, queda claro lo que quieres lograr. Sugiero que te tomes el tiempo de incluir en tu pregunta un pequeño conjunto de los datos de entrada que tienes y la salida que esperas obtener **con esos mismos datos** de entrada. Eso, además de explicar de la manera más clara que te sea posible lo que esperas lograr. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Guissepi, tienes casi todos los elementos para obtener el resultado que esperas, solo te faltó incluir la suma.

Por favor prueba con la siguiente modificación en la primera línea:

```
--                                                 aquí                    y aquí
--                                         | ----------------- |   | ------------------  |  
--                                         V                       V
(select t1.ACODIGO,t1.ADESCRI,t1.AUNIDAD, SUM(t1.Linea) as Linea, SUM(t1.Linea2) as Linea2 from(
        SELECT  ...
```

Comment: Gutierrez gracias por el comentario pero no quiero sumar, quier que los 0 no aparezcan y que solo muestre una fila por articulo de todos modos hice tu recomendacion y no sale lo que quiero, solo lo junta [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyjYS.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyjYS.png)

Comment: Recuerda que los comentarios no son respuesta. Una fila por artículo? `Select distinct acodigo, adescri, aunidad` ? _Oh.. the irony_

Comment: @pablo gutierrez gracias por los comentarios pero no me sale lo q quiero :C---------psdt. soy nuevo en este sitio xd me estoy familiarizando la manera de como responder gg